# how to anikmate this svg while scrollling?

Tags: svg, css-animations

```
  <svg class="desktop-img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="821.334" height="509.375" viewBox="0 0 821.334 509.375"  preserveAspectRatio="true" version="1.1">
               

              
                    <path id="Path_244" class="path" data-name="Path 244" d="M-15596.515,315.963s-64.138,86.644-155.208,86.033-153.659-47.666-263.047-49.682-212.582,34.27-284.648,148.329-38.8,246.323-38.8,246.323" transform="translate(16375.888 -274.001)" fill="none" stroke="#ef404a" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="60" ></path>
               
           
                </svg>
```

Want animate this curve while scrolling

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you could start reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484577/how-to-scroll-into-view-a-part-of-a-svg-path-animation) and then when you developed your idea further you can update your own question it you run into issues.